# Cannot convert value of type 'Double.Type' to expected argument type 'Double'

Tags: swift, api, openweathermap

I'm trying to pass GPS coordinates from one function into the another but it's not working.

```
func defaultCity(defLat: Double, defLon: Double){
    let url = URL(string: "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(defLat)&lon=\(defLon)&appid=626a124ef0844d2e021329c38a5dfafd")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("Problem extracting data")
        } else {
            if let urlContent = data {
                do {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    print("Geoloc coords: \(jsonResult)")
                }catch{
                    print("Json Processing has failed or city name not recognized.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I'm trying to get the `defLon` and `defLat` from `currentLocation` into `defaultCity`. How do I pass these variables along?

```
func currentlocation(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    if let location = locations.first{
        //print(location.coordinate)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        print("My location is \(myLocation)")
        let myLon = location.coordinate.longitude
        let myLat = location.coordinate.latitude
        defaultCity(defLat: myLat, defLon: myLon)
        print(location.altitude)
        print(location.speed)
    }
}
```

When I call the function in viewDidLoad() with this line:

```
defaultCity(defLat : Double, defLon: Double)
```

That's where I'm getting the error that I can't figure out. Strange the red arrow is only under the first `Double`.My `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    openCityAlert()
    getAndDisplayWeather()
    //for use when app is open and in background
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line exactly does the error occur? `defaultCity(defLat: myLat, defLon: myLon)` looks correct at first sight, and I cannot see that you *call* the function with `defaultCity(defLat : Double, defLon: Double)` anywhere.

Comment: @MartinR The OP states that they have the line `defaultCity(defLat : Double, defLon: Double)` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Then it would be helpful to see that call in the context, because it is unclear what it should achieve.

Comment: @MartinR that is where i call the function

Comment: @J.Derbs Why are you calling `defaultCity` from `viewDidLoad`? It would probably help if you [edit] your question to include your entire `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Edit it how and where? Sorry I'm really new to this and I'm 13 :)

Comment: I put the [edit] link right in my comment. You can also click the "edit" link under your question.

Comment: What did you change I can't see the difference.

Comment: I didn't change anything. I'm asking you to [edit] (<-- click that link) your question and post your `viewDidLoad` method. And I'm also asking you why you are trying to call the `defaultCity` method from your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I don't understand where else I would call the defaultCity method. (I posted my viewDidLoad()

Comment: Now your question makes no sense. You originally stated in your question that you have the line `defaultCity(defLat : Double, defLon: Double)` in your `viewDidLoad` method. But now that you have posted your entire `viewDidLoad` method, there is no such line in there.

Comment: Where should it be?

Comment: Reiterating my above question: *Where* in your code *exactly* does the compiler error occur?

Comment: I don't understand where I should call:     'defaultCity(defLat: myLat, defLon: myLon)' that is the only question/error I have left. That is my question. I only get compiler errors when I try to move     defaultCity(defLat: myLat, defLon: myLon)
around. @rmaddy

Comment: @rmaddy The reason the line is not there is because I get an error when it is there.

Comment: But you already call it from `func currentlocation`. What are you actually trying to achieve by calling it from somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not sure if currentLoction is being called because no data from defaultCity is being printed in the console. Which is why I'm curious if I can print it from somewhere else. @MartinR

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it something like

```
defaultCity(defLat : myLat, defLon: myLon)
```

`Double` is used when defining the function not calling.

Comment: I did that and now i have an error of unresolved identifier for myLat and myLon

Comment: I had just given the examples. You need to pass your variables where you are holding your latitude and longitude.

Comment: what  do you mean?

Comment: I mean. If myLat and myLong are not defined in the scope where you are calling the function , you will get this error. Don't call it from viewDidLoad.

Comment: I thought I already defined myLat and myLon in these lines: let myLon = location.coordinate.longitude
            let myLat = location.coordinate.latitude

Comment: they are not defined globally. They are local to currentlocation function. So you can use them there. But not in viewDidLoad

Comment: If I remove then from viewDidLoad i get another error...Where would i define them? Sorry I'm 13 :)

Comment: You can define them globally. Remove 'let' from currentlocation. Define them inside viewController class but outside any funciton. with 'var'. Also I would suggest you to start with some basic stuff first.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq No, do make those variables global. That's the wrong solution.

Comment: If i define them outside a function the gps stuff gives me another error...

Comment: I would suggest to go through some basics first. That way you will save a lot of time and enjoy coding a lot more. Like variable declarations, there scope, function calling, return values etc.

Comment: I did, for two weeks.

Comment: Thats great. Start implementing some basic functions. Get used to it.

Comment: I did all of your suggestions. When I declare the var myLon, Lat inside view controller but outside of functions It won't work because it is also referencing the gps location, which is inside a function.

Comment: Yes you are right. You will have your correct lat and lon when the user location is updated. So that is the right place to call it. :) . In viewDidLoad you don't know the lat and long.

Comment: You should not call it from viewDidLoad. You will not get the error. If you call it form right place. The location will not be available until currentlocation is called.

Comment: I would be offline now. You can drop your project to me if required, along with queries. I will try to fix them.

Comment: Well I got all the error away, but do you know where I should call     defaultCity(defLat: myLat, defLon: myLon)
Inside of currentLocation()?

Comment: let myLon = Double(location.coordinate.longitude)
        let myLat =Double( location.coordinate.latitude).. values are float actually .. just try using this if it works